# $f: X\rightarrow \mathbb{C}, \alpha \in \overline{X}.$ Show that $\lim_{z\rightarrow \alpha }f(z)=w \Leftrightarrow f(z_n) \rightarrow w$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

$f: X\rightarrow \mathbb{C}, \alpha \in \overline{X}.$ Show that $\lim_{z\rightarrow \alpha }f(z)=w \Leftrightarrow f(z_n) \rightarrow w$ for every sequence $\left \{ z_n \right \}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\subseteq X$ that satisfies $z_n\rightarrow \alpha $.

I have a question on "$\Rightarrow $" direction.

I thought it would be easier to do casework such as

i) $\alpha \in X$

ii) $\alpha \in \overline{X} \setminus X$

The first case was easy to prove, but there's a little doubtful part in my proof for case ii).

Here's my proof for case ii).

We want to show that $\alpha$ is a limit point of $X$.

Suppose $\alpha$ is not a limit point of $X$.

$\Rightarrow \nexists \beta \in X$ in some neighborhood of $\alpha$. (Assume $\beta \neq \alpha$).

$\Rightarrow \exists \varepsilon > 0$ s.t $B(\alpha ,\varepsilon )\cap X = \left \{\alpha  \right \}$

$\Rightarrow \alpha $ is an isolated point of $X$.

But, then $\alpha \in X$ which is a contradiction. (This is the part that is doubtful).

$\Rightarrow \alpha $ is a limit point of $X$.

$\Rightarrow \forall \left \{ z_n \right \}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\subseteq X$ s.t $z_n \rightarrow \alpha$, we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }f(z_n) = \lim_{z\rightarrow \alpha }f(z)= w$.

I did it like this after reading a sub-content 'limit point' of "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(topology)"

However, at the same time, I think this proof doesn't work because $\alpha$ being not the limit point of $X$ doesn't necessarily imply $\alpha \in X$.

Can I get some help with this?

Comment: You don't want to prove that $\alpha$ is a limit point of $X$.  Knowing that $\alpha$ is in the closure of $X$ tells you that (I'm assuming that $X \subseteq \Bbb C$).  You want to take an arbitrary sequence of $z_n$ within $X$ that converges to $\alpha$ and show (a) $\lim f(z_n)$ esists, and (b) $\lim f(z_n) = w$.  If you're using the definition of limit in $\Bbb C$ that I suspect you're using, that shouldn't be hard.

Comment: Great. Thank you @RobertShore